# Get object value by property reference not working on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, object, ios7, mobile-safari

This is my object:

```
var charsObj = {"drive":{"status":"inprogress","data":"some data","history":"the text of my history"}}


function getNote(x) { 
   if ( x in charsObj) { 
     console.log(charsObj[x])
    } else { 
      console.log('nothing', charsObj[x])
    }
}
```

if I call `getNote('drive')` it returns my object value as expected EXCEPT iOS returns `'nothing', undefined`.

How do I get this to work on iOS?

Comment: where is charsObj created in your code

Comment: `if (x in charsObj)` - is that valid? - wouldn't it be `if (charsObj.hasOwnProperty(x))`

Comment: @tymeJV: Tried both ways. made no difference.