# Angular: update scope var within child function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

In app.js:

```
.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.history = {
            drive:  "Jim"
        };

 $scope.getNote = function () {
     $scope.history.drive ="Eric";
 }

 };
```

In HTML View:

```
<textarea name="notesdata">{{history.drive}}</textarea>
```

When the view loads I see Jim in the textarea. But when I call getNote() I would expect it to change to Eric and its not. What am I doing wrong?

I tried adding $scope.apply(); after $scope.history.drive ="Eric"; but then I get a "Error: $apply in progress"

Comment: I finally got it to work via a fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/u67kov5e/

Now I have another question directly related to this in that iOS cant get the object property. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26024488/get-object-value-by-property-reference-not-working-on-ios

Answer (score 2):

Just a typo.

This:

```
$scope.getNote() = function () {
  $scope.history.drive ="Eric";
}
```

Should be this:

```
$scope.getNote = function () {
  $scope.history.drive ="Eric";
}
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u67kov5e/

Comment: Your right thats how it was originally. typo on my part entering the example. updated the example.

Comment: Oh. The controller code is fine. How are you calling it?

Comment: from another function in the same controller like on a button click. I call $scope.getNote() directly.

Comment: Can I please see it? Again, the code you posted here is not wrong. So the problem exists elsewhere.

Comment: pasted previously. I should be able to call $scope.getNote() from anywhere in the same controller and have that value updated in the view.

Comment: Again. Nothing you have posted is wrong. If you post all of your code, I will be able to help you. Here is what you posted, and it's working just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/u67kov5e/ I need to be able to see how you're calling things and more of the view if you want help.

Comment: Here is a more detailed fiddle of exactly what Im trying to do..  http://jsfiddle.net/u67kov5e/  Im actually trying to bind that value to a localstorage value.. It seems to work in the fiddle but not my code in my app. In addition on iOS the charsObj.hasOwnProperty(x) returns undefined Thats another major issue.

Comment: Think you accidentally copied the same fiddle I posted. :)

Comment: oops i actually updated the same one. thought it would save. guess not. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are probably close with your thought about `$scope.apply()`.

If you are calling `$scope.getNote()` inside an event listener that *isn't* in the 'angular world', for example you have bound to a 'click' event manually without using `ng-click`, then you will need to trigger a digest when you call `$scope.getNote()`

The best way to do this is like so:

```
// pseudocode representing non-angular event
on('someEvent', function (){
  // trigger a digest to tell angular about this event
  $scope.$apply(function (){
    $scope.getNote();
  });
});
```

The fiddle works fine because the `ng-click` directive triggers the digest in its internals.